# Execution error while building android phone gap build

Tags: android, phonegap

when i Run the command `phonegap build android` it gives me the the error `execution failed for task 'mergeDebugResources'` I am implementing the [plugin](https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt) `cordova-background-geolocation-lt` and following the same as explained there and install the same SDK's.
[image: Image shpowing error after running the debug command]

complete error
[image]

Here is some more info about DEBUG after running the command `gradlew.bat --info build clean`

[image]

Comment: does plugin file exists in node_modules folder in your project directory ?

Comment: yes @PrateekBhardwaj

Comment: Even now i removed the plugin and the code from the file related to this plugin, then tried again to get the build and its giving me the same error.

Comment: please share complete error which you are getting in command prompt.

Comment: updated in question @PrateekBhardwaj

Comment: @PrateekBhardwaj I have found the error causing plugin in my project the error was due to this plugin `cordova.plugins.diagnostic` when i removed this plugin it works fine. But now whats the solution, I also want to use this plugin `cordova.plugins.diagnostic`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a clash with some other plugin. I have tried adding the diagnostic plugin to a brand new project and tried building. That worked fine.